# Need a list previous quarters based on current date

Tags: java, date, calendar

My requirement is simple, I need to show newsletters for last 3 quarters in the screen.
For this I'll have to set the news letter pdf links in session.
So if the user logs in on Feb 2013, he should see 3 links namely

```
'Newsletter Q1 2013'
'Newsletter Q4 2012'
'Newsletter Q3 2012'
```

Here is the code so far,

```
        String newsLetter1 = null;
        String newsLetter2 = null;
        String newsLetter3 = null;
           Date date  = new Date();
           Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
           cal.setTime(date);
           int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
           int quarter = (month / 3) + 1;
    //Do something here to populate newsLetter1, newsLetter2 , newsLetter3 
      variables based on current date 
           session.setAttribute("newsLetter1", "Newsletter  "+newsLetter1 );
           session.setAttribute("newsLetter2", "Newsletter  "+newsLetter2);
           session.setAttribute("newsLetter3", "Newsletter  "+newsLetter3);
```

I've given it a good thought, but couldn't think of any possible solutions. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In every iteration you can sub 3 monthes from current date and calculate quarter by the formula you already have.

```
int newsLetters = 3;
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
for (int i = 0; i < newsLetters; i++) {
  cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, -3);
  int quarter = (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) / 3) + 1;
  System.out.println("Newsletter Q" + quarter + " " + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
}
```

The output:

```
Newsletter Q2 2013
Newsletter Q1 2013
Newsletter Q4 2012
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can find quarter as follows

```
 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int quarter=0;
    if(month<5){
        quarter=1;
        // news letter belongs to quarter 1
    }else if(month<9){
       quarter=2;
       // news letter belongs to quarter 2
    }else {
        quarter=3;
       // news letter belongs to quarter 3
    }
```

If you want to year with quarter use following

```
 Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int year =cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    if(month<5){
        System.out.println(year+" "+"quarter "+1);
    }else if(month<9){
        System.out.println(year+" "+"quarter "+2);
    }else {
        System.out.println(year+" "+"quarter "+3);
    }
```

Comment: I need the year also. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int q1 = (month / 3) + 1;
    int q2 = q1 == 1 ? 4 : q1 - 1;
    int q3 = q2 == 1 ? 4 : q2 - 1;
    session.setAttribute("newsLetter1", "Newsletter  " + q1);
    session.setAttribute("newsLetter2", "Newsletter  " + q2);
    session.setAttribute("newsLetter3", "Newsletter  " + q3);
```

notes

1) Locale is not relevant in this case

2) cal.setTime(date) is not needed, Calendar.getInstance already returns an instance based on the current time